# Lua - iterating through nested list

Tags: lua

I'm going to simplify the situation as much as I can. I have the following code:

```
windows = { "window1", "window2" }

window1 = {
x = 100
y = 100
properties = { active = false, width = 200, height = 200 }
}

window2 = {
x = 0
y = 0
properties = { active = false, width = 200, height = 200 }
}
```

If I do the following, I get the correct output:

```
print (window1.x)
OUTPUT: 0
print (window1.properties.active)
OUTPUT: false
```

HOWEVER, if I iterate through the list, I get "nil" values for "l.x" and "l.properties.active":

```
for _,l in ipairs(windows) do
    print (l)
    print (l.x)
    print (l.properties.active)
end
```

Is there a different way I need to iterate through the variables in the lists, so I can get the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a nested table, but just a table containing strings. And, as you just saw, a string doesn't contain a value for the key `"x"`.

You have to put the *tables* in a sequence:

```
local window1 = {...} -- first table

local window2 = {...} -- second table

local windows = {window1, window2}

for _,l in ipairs(windows) do
    -- do stuff with l
end
```

Or, if you want to keep the list of strings and iterate over the strings, put the windows in a second table using these strings as a key.

```
local windowNames = { "window1", "window2" }
local windows = {}

windows.window1 = {...} -- first table

windows.window2 = {...} -- second table

for _,l in ipairs(windowNames) do
    local ourWindow = windows[l]
    -- do stuff with ourWindow
end
```

Comment: That's correct. Are you aware of how I can use those strings as variable names in Lua?

Comment: @Neekoy yes, but it depends if you want the tables to be ordered or not.

Comment: @Neekoy I added an example which keeps the order of the strings. I also added `local` keywords, as a variable without that keyword is added to the *global scope*.

Comment: Just tested this and it worked! Thank you so very much, I definitely wouldn't have come to the conclusion myself (at least at this point).